# Telerik RadTimePicker time selection issue on setting end time

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using `ASP.NET 3.5` with `C#`, `telerik asp-net ajax` version 2012.1.515.35.

I have a RadTimepicker inside an UserControl.

I want to restrict entering of future time. Suppose I have 7:00 AM on my computer then user can select / insert maximum time 7:00 am, not more than that.

I also I need to show the RadTimepicker's time as per logged-in user's timezone. For that I am taking DateTime.UTCNow and converting it to user's time with some extension method.

The ascx page's RadTimepicker control's configuration is :

```
<telerik:RadTimePicker ID="rtpVitals" runat="server" Width="85" DateInput-DateFormat="HH:mm"
    TimeView-TimeFormat="HH:mm" Skin="Hay">
    <Calendar UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False" UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" ViewSelectorText="x">
    </Calendar>
    <TimeView CellSpacing="-1" TimeFormat="HH:mm" OnClientTimeSelected="OnClientTimeSelected">
    </TimeView>
    <TimePopupButton CssClass="" ImageUrl="" HoverImageUrl="" onblur="hideTimePopup('rtpVitals');">
    </TimePopupButton>
    <DatePopupButton Visible="False" CssClass="" ImageUrl="" HoverImageUrl=""></DatePopupButton>
    <DateInput CssClass="txtbox txtBack-Color" BorderColor="#D0D1AE" BorderStyle="Solid"
        BorderWidth="1" ForeColor="#333333" onblur="enterDateTime();">
    </DateInput>
</telerik:RadTimePicker>
```

And in `Page_PreRender()` event of UserControl i call following method to set the RadTimePicker's property :

```
private void setTimePicker()
{
    try
    {
        TimeZoneInfo t = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
        DateTime d = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUserTime(t);

        rtpVitals.TimeView.StartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

        if (d.Hour < 1)
        {
            rtpVitals.TimeView.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, d.Minute/2, 0);

            if (d.Minute <= 1)
            {
                rtpVitals.TimeView.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, d.Second/2);
            }
        }
        else if (d.Hour < 12)
        {
            rtpVitals.TimeView.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rtpVitals.TimeView.Interval = new TimeSpan(1, 00, 0);
        }

        rtpVitals.TimeView.EndTime = new TimeSpan(d.Hour, d.Minute, d.Second);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The extension method to convert time is as below :

```
public static DateTime ToUserTime(this DateTime utcTime, TimeZoneInfo toUserTimeZone)
{
    try
    {
        utcTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utcTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        //Create the userTime object
        //Set it to UTC time by default. It would be changed later
        DateTime userTime = utcTime;

        //Convert the time
        TimeZoneInfo fromTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
        userTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcTime, fromTimeZone, toUserTimeZone);

        //Return the TimeZone
        return userTime;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**FYI :** My computer's timezone is **"(UTC+5:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi**".

Set your PC's time between **8:30 AM to 10:30 AM**, and run the project. The time-view will show you time upto 23:00 hours with 1 hour interval, but selection of any time will give you the error icon i.e. invalid time inside RadTimePicker.

You have any idea why it is happening?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
rtpVitals.TimeView.StartTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: It will return the current time of day. I want to show time from 12 AM i.e 00:00 hours to current time of logged in user.